# locator.waitFor: Target closed in Playwright error even though the "Wait" handled

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

Im trying to implement Playwright/TS Page Object Model framework for a web app.

So in this case Im automating login successful scenario by asserting user can see the Dashboard text.

But Im getting the following error.

```
Error: locator.waitFor: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for getByRole('heading', { name: 'Dashboard' }) to be visible
============================================================

   at ../pages/DashboardPage.ts:32

  30 |
  31 |      async isDashboardTxtVisible(){
> 32 |       await this.txtDashboard.waitFor({state: "visible"});
     |                               ^
  33 |        return this.txtDashboard.isVisible();
  34 |     }
  35 | }

    at DashboardPage.isDashboardTxtVisible (/Users/ivit/Desktop/Projects/QA/Playwright/PWPOM_V4/pages/DashboardPage.ts:32:31)
    at /Users/ivit/Desktop/Projects/QA/Playwright/PWPOM_V4/tests/login.spec.ts:8:34
```

Here is my code.

This is the spec file Im executing(login.spec.ts)

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { App } from '../pages/App';

test("Checking whether user can logged in", async({page}) => {
  const app = new App(page);
  await app.LoginPage.visit();
  await app.LoginPage.login("Admin","admin123");
  await expect(app.DashboardPage.isDashboardTxtVisible()).toBeTruthy();
  
});
```

DashoardPage.ts

```
import { Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class DashboardPage {

  readonly page: Page;
 
  readonly lnkLeave: Locator;
  readonly lnkPIM: Locator;
  readonly txtDashboard: Locator;

  
  constructor(page: Page){
    this.page = page;

    this.lnkLeave = page.getByPlaceholder('Username');
    this.lnkPIM = page.getByPlaceholder('Password');
    this.txtDashboard = page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Dashboard' });
}
   

 

     async clickLinkLeave(){
           this.lnkLeave.click();
    }

    async clickLinkPIM(){
        this.lnkPIM.click();
    }

     async isDashboardTxtVisible(){
      await this.txtDashboard.waitFor({state: "visible"});  <<<< Here is the issue
       return this.txtDashboard.isVisible();
    }
}
```

LoginPage.ts

```
import { Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class LoginPage {

  readonly page: Page;
 
  readonly txtUsername: Locator;
  readonly txtPassword: Locator;
  readonly btnLogin: Locator;

  
  constructor(page: Page){
    this.page = page;
 
    this.txtUsername = page.getByPlaceholder('Username');
    this.txtPassword = page.getByPlaceholder('Password');;
    this.btnLogin = page.getByRole('button', { name: ' Login' });
}
   

 

     async login(username: string, password: string){
      await this.txtUsername.type(username);
      await this.txtPassword.type(password);
      await this.btnLogin.click();
     
    }

     async visit(){
      await this.page.goto("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");     
    }
}
```

App,.ts (This is kind of a wrapper class, where i don't need to create objects from a page class inside tests every time)

```
import { Page } from "@playwright/test";
import { LoginPage } from "./LoginPage";
import { DashboardPage } from "./DashboardPage";

export class App {
    protected page: Page;
    
    constructor(page: Page){
        this.page = page;
    }

    public get LoginPage(): LoginPage{
        return new LoginPage(this.page);
    }

    public get DashboardPage(): DashboardPage{
        return new DashboardPage(this.page);
    }
}
```

What is the issue here? is it that the way Im using wait? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to fix this issue by adding inside and outside awaits

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { App } from '../pages/App';

test("Checking whether user can logged in", async({page}) => {
  const app = new App(page);
  await app.LoginPage.visit();
  await app.LoginPage.login("Admin","admin123");
  await expect( await app.DashboardPage.isDashboardTxtVisible()).toBeTruthy();
  
});
```

Comment: This is not the recommended way to assert . Use web assertions , see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76699893

Comment: my issue was not about the assertion @VishalAggarwal I think you have misunderstood the question

Comment: The way you have used the assertion ("expect") is incorrect. It's not about your question.

Answer (score 2):

> [isVisible](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-is-visible) does not wait for the  element to be visible like
> [toBeVisible](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible) web assertion which is the correct way to assert
> something which may take some time.

The below statement will wait for 5 seconds for the element to be visible.

Example:

```
await expect(page.getByText('Welcome')).toBeVisible({timeout:5000});
```